# TableViewCell copy property changed in Swift 3

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a fairly simple question to ask.In my tableView, I am using canPerformAction to copy selected cell by applying long press to the selected cell.Everytime, When this action performed it shows the **'Copy'** popup over the  UITableViewCell in Xcode 7.But, After, I moved to Xcode 8 popup shows with more options like **Cut**,**Copy**and **Paste** like the screenshot below.Is there any possible solution to show only **copy** popup.**I can upload a code on request**. But, the code is fairly simple as you guys know.not much to show.Help is very  much appreciated.

[image]

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though not sure why it is so, can you try to specify it explicitly by overriding canPerformAction delegate,

```
override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    if action == #selector(cut(_:)) {
      return false
    }
    if action == #selector(paste(_:)) {
      return false
    }
    if action == #selector(select(_:)) {
      return false
    }
    if action == #selector(selectAll(_:)) {
      return false
    }
    ...

    return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
  }
```

Comment: I thing your answer will work.i will give it a try.thanks